# Is there a sense in which a formal theory can be more or less "metamathematically aware"?

Tags: soft-question, constructive-mathematics, type-theory, meta-math, intuitionistic-logic

For example, in classical logic, because of the law of the excluded middle, all propositions must be true or false, so in order to prove that a proposition is *actually* independent of the theory, we need to use some metamathematical ideas. However, in intuitionistic logic, we can prove $\neg\neg p$, corresponding to the independence of the statement $p$, without having to use any metamathematical ideas.

Also, though I am just now learning about it, constructive type theories, with their reification of proofs as mathematical objects seems to me like it should be much deeper in metamathematical character. Moreover, [this](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/Sem.html) page claims Martin-Löf Type Theory was developed in the tradition of "metamathematical modeling".

In what sense do constructive type theories, or more generally, other theories like intuitionistic logic "model" metamathematical ideas? Is there some rigorous notion of (semi-) interpretability of metamathematical concepts in a theory?

Comment: Not clear how $\lnot\lnot p$ corresponds to the "independence of $p$." If $p$ is true, the $\lnot\lnot p$ is true, even in intuitionist logic, so $\lnot\lnot p$ does not say anything about the indepedence of $p$.

Comment: There's an interesting fact about $\lnot\lnot$. In topos theory, a topos that models intuitionistic logic has a "topology," $\lnot\lnot$, that lets you "booleanize" the topos, and that a lot of classical independence forcing proofs can be described as a two-step: Create an intuitionistic topos from a "standard" set theory topos, then booleanize that intuitionistic topos.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right, I suppose it would have to be $\neg\neg p \wedge \neg p$ to not include the case where $p$ is true, I suppose?

Comment: Intuitionist logic shouldn't let you prove $q\land \lnot q$, either, even if $q$ is $\lnot p$. Proof by contradiction still works in intuitionistic logic, you just get: $(p\implies (q\land \lnot q))\implies(\lnot p)$, and you aren't allowed to cancel $\lnot\lnot p\implies p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hmm, interesting. Intuitively yes, $\neg \neg p \wedge \neg p$ should represent "independence", in the sense that we can neither refute, nor fail to refute the proposition $p$, yet, such a proposition is in fact contradictory in Intuitionistic logic. Apparently Heyting noted this, saying it: "...amounts to saying that a demonstrably unsolvable problem cannot exist.". This makes me wonder if such an attempt to express logical independence of propositions inside a theory is always doomed to fail for metamathematical reasons.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, maybe what I was getting at in my last sentence isn't true. I forgot about your comment about "booleanizing" topoi.

Answer (score 0):

[Provability logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provability_logic) and [Interpretability logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability_logic) both use modal logic to study what a system can prove about its own metamathematical properties. According to [this thesis](https://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Reports/MoL-2012-10.text.pdf) it seems to be mainly focused on studying formal theories of arithmetic, though the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provability_logic) makes me think the theory is more general than that. Though, with some preliminary searching, I couldn't find any use of provability logic to deduce the "metamathematical awareness" of common foundational systems or logics themselves, so I would be interested in anyone could find some papers towards that direction of study.